# Failed loading xdebug.so undefined symbol zend_sort

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to use xdebug in phpstorm. I have successfully installed xdebug and set the path in php.ini. However, I am still getting message that "failed loading usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:undefined sybol:zend_sort".

My php executable is "php-cgi-5.6.20"

My php.ini:
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"

Comment: Need more info. But so far it's possible that 1) you are mixing nts (non thread safe) version of xdebug with ts (thread safe) version of PHP (or other way around); 2) you are using xdebug that is not meant to work with this PHP version (e.g. using xdebug compiled for PHP 7.0 with actual PHP 5.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same zend_extension path try to use php executable '7.0', and not '5.6'. It worked for me.